# WKInterfaceLabel goes dark after reaching a certain height

Tags: swift, watchos-3, watchos-4

I am trying to display a lot of data in a WKInterfaceLabel. At some point I've realized that the label goes dark entirely at long texts.

At first I thought it's to do with the amount of lines but after a quick test I figured that the amount of lines don't stand in direct correlation to the "going dark"-thing. I then proceeded to test with a string that contains the letter `b` 8926 times which worked. Setting this number to 8927 again broke the label.

I changed `b` to `i` which allowed for more characters; I was able to display 15927 so I knew it's not related to string length. I then changed the font size to a bigger one and the Label went dark again which lead me to the conclusion that the `WKInterfaceLabel` is limited in its height.

My workaround would be to add more than one `WKInterfaceLabel` to the screen and start writing data to it as soon as the first one is full BUT **I couldn't find any info as to how to get WKInterfaceLabel size**.

How can I get around this character limitation or how can I get the height of the label? `WKInterfaceGroup` doesn't seem to have a `size` property either.

When the label goes dark, the rest of the InterfaceController remains usable, scrollable, clickable, navigatable and memory usage jumps to 36.3 so I think this issue is rather arbitrary.

Here's the code I've used for testing

```
//font is set to "Caption 2"
var labelText = ""
//for i in 0...8927 { // breaks with "b"
for i in 0...15927 { //works with "Caption 2" but breaks with "Body" font
    labelText.append("i")
}
self.label?.setText(labelText)
```

PS: I do not want to use a table view

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is one of the best questions from a new user that I've ever seen, congratulations. It has a clear MCVE and a layout that is very nice to read. Good luck for finding a solution to this awful bug.

Comment: Thank you my friend, that's very nice of you! Enjoy your weekend